# Disable Server Manager from startup for Remote Desktop users with GPO for no MMC

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, windows

I have a GPO that restricts MMC creation. When users who this GPO applies to login they are greeted with "MMC could not create the snap-in."

I understand there is normally a checkbox that prevents Server Manager from coming up but of course I cannot uncheck it without seeing the MMC, and besides, I would have to have every user do this.

How can I prevent the Server Manager from loading for users who cannot use it anyway?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To Set it though Group Policy, follow these steps :

1. Click on **Start** > **Run**
2. Type **GPEDIT**> **MSC** > hit **OK**
3. The **Local Group Policy Editor** snap-in will open
4. The policy that we are interested in can be found by expanding the following:
   **Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Server Manager**
5. Right click on the policy : **Do not display Server Manager automatically at logon** , click **Properties**
6. Select the RadioButton beside **Enable** > Click on **OK**
7. Close the **Local Group Policy Editor** snap-in
8. Click on **Start** > **Run** > type **gpudpate** > click on **OK**